# Read a key combination with bash script

Tags: bash

For the following code, I want to be able to hold down one button and press another to execute a script, like a "Ctrl"+"upArrow" key combination.I guess that some sort of 'key-down' and 'key-up' functionality is what I need. Any Ideas ?

```
#!/bin/bash
    read -rsn1 input
    while [ "$input" = "a" ]; do
        read -rsn1 input2
        if [ "$input" = "b" ]; then #spaces are important for control flow in bash-script
            echo "Rest in pepperoni memeroni";
        fi

    done
```

Comment: You could use the function key in this example:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a shortcut key, use the bash `bind` command.

Example: use `F6` function key to clear screen

```
bind '"\e[17~":"clear\n"'
```

Of course, you would replace `clear` with your script.

To figure out what the `F6` symbol is, just enter the `read` command and press `F6`.

[image]

NOTE: The `^[` on the screen shot is the `\e` in the code.

Comment: I've edited my post, I specifically want to use the control button in combination with an arrow key in order to active a code sequence. Will bind work for this just as well ?

Comment: Yes, it will work.  I tested CNTL-Left_Arrow, which is code ^[OD and my example above still worked.  So you would do `bind '"\eOD":"your_script\n"'`

Comment: Just in case anyone asks, these 'bindings' are removed when your login session ends.  To keep them permanent from session-to-session, put the `bind` commands in your bash terminal session / login script (e.g. the `.bashrc` script).